# Oracle 12c Username forgot

Tags: database, oracle

a couple of days ago I installed oracle 12c. I ran it after a days or two but I completely lost my Username, I do remember my password but not username. I there any way by which I can see what username I set

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can login as `SYS`, you can use:

```
select *
from dba_users
```

This will give all the users, including the one you defined; [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_5081.htm#REFRN23302) you find something more.

Comment: where to use this command ?
I tried to login as SYS without any password, also tried my own password that I set for my username but still fruitless.

Answer (score 0):

There is new procedure for generating password since Oracle 11g. You can use

```
create or replace function get_hash_11g(p_password varchar2, p_salt varchar2) return varchar2 is
    lv_pwd_raw    RAW(128);
    lv_enc_raw    RAW(2048);
  BEGIN 
    lv_pwd_raw    := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_password) || hextoraw(p_salt);
    lv_enc_raw    := sys.dbms_crypto.hash(lv_pwd_raw, 3);

    return lv_enc_raw;
  end get_hash_11g;
/
```

Then run select

```
select w.name from sys.user$ w
where substr(w.spare4, 3, 40) = get_hash_11g(/*your password*/'&pass', substr(spare4, 43, 20));
/
```

Comment: I'm very new to oracle, 
where should I type/select all this ?

Comment: This works only from user who has priviliges for sys.user$(In most cases it is SYS user).

Comment: You can connect as from command line upon user from ora_dba group.
I think it is the user who installed Oracle
sqlplus /nolog
connect / as sysdba

alter user sys identified by <new password>

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to invoke *sqlplus* then follow this:

`sqlplus:/ as sysdba` - this is the command needed to login as *sys*.

`password:` - don't give any *password*. Just hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

`SQL> select username from dba_users;` - this command will give list of *users* in the database.

Answer (score -1):

Set up the following environment variables. They are not necessary for the process itself, but will help you navigate. In this case my domain is called "ClassicDomain". Remember to change the value to match your domain.

```
export MW_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/middleware
export DOMAIN_HOME=$MW_HOME/user_projects/domains/ClassicDomain
```

Shut down the WebLogic domain.

```
$ $DOMAIN_HOME/bin/stopWebLogic.sh
```

Rename the data folder.

```
$ mv $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/data $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/data-old
```

Reset the password using the following command. Remember to substitute the appropriate username and password.

```
$ cd $DOMAIN_HOME/security
$ java weblogic.security.utils.AdminAccount <username> <password> .
```